# Why it is legal here to create lvalue reference to prvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I have code below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    for(int& v : std::vector<int>{1,3,5,10}) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
        v++; // Does this cause undefined behavior?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand, the vector is prvalue, and cannot bind to `int&`, but this one works correctly?

Is it because for range loop is simply macro expansion and a temporary variable would be created for the vector?

Comment: Downvoter: Can you elaborate on what's wrong with this question? I think it's perfectly legitimate and highlights a nuance of how the range-based for loop works.

Comment: The vector isn't bound to an `int&`.   The members within it are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The range-based `for` loop is most definitely *not* macro expansion. It's a separate construct of the language. Still, while the vector itself is a prvalue, its member functions still operate normally. So its `operator[]` (or dereferencing its iterator) returns a normal lvalue reference etc.

Of course, such references are only valid as long as the vector itself exists. Its lifetime lasts for the entire range-based `for` loop (that is mandated by the range-based `for` loop specification in the standard), so all is well.

As far as value categories are concerned, it's the same as this (which is also [legal](http://ideone.com/6hUR5C)):

```
int &i = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}[0];
```

Of course, unlike the one in the range-based `for` loop, this `i` reference become dangling immediately. But the principle is the same.

Consider also this: the language has no way of knowing that the lvalue reference returned by the iterator's `operator *` or the vector's `operator[]` refers to something whose lifetime is bound to that of the vector. It simply returns an lvalue reference, so it's bindable.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the crucial point: Why is the lifetime of the vector extended? Why does it last for the entire loop?

Comment: @MWid I actually understood the question as "why can a prvalue bind to an lvalue reference?" not as "why is the prvalue lifetime extended?" But in case I misunderstood, I edited a bit more info in.

Answer (score 18):

According to the C++ ISO spec, the range-based for loop is formally defined to be equivalent to

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
         __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
         range_declaration = *__begin; 
         loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

Note that "equivalent to" doesn't mean "expands out to as a macro," but rather "has the exact same behavior as". This equivalence isn't a macro in the traditional sense (i.e. it's not a `#define`), but rather is given in the ISO spec as a formal way of defining the semantics of what the range-based for loop does. The implementation of the range-based for loop can be whatever the compiler likes, as long as the behavior is exactly identical to the behavior given above.

In this context, `range_expression` is a prvalue, but it's then bound to `__range`, which is an lvalue. The iterators obtained that scan over `__range` are also lvalues, and so when the iterators are dereferenced to yield the individual values in the range, those values will be lvalues.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that `__range` does reference lifetime extension (what is the standardese name for it?) of prvalue `std::vector<int>{1,3,5,10}`, which is important to get why this works.  And `std::vector<int>&& __range` is an rvalue reference, but rvalue references act as lvalue references after declaration outside of `decltype` expressions.

Comment: What do you mean by "but rvalue references act as lvalue references"? This sounds a lot more confusing than "`__range` is a name, hence it is an lvalue."

Comment: Although one can reason about range-based for loops using the full specification it seems unnecessary. In this case I think it would be better not to (or at least not to leave it at that), because answering the question by simply addressing the error in the OPs (presumed) reasoning will be more informative. (The error being, I believe, that the OP is attributing value categories to objects rather than expressions, and reasoning about the value category of the elements of the range based on that misunderstanding.)

Comment: @Fred "foo is a name, hence..." is problematic. `std::errc::bad_address` is a name, but it is not an lvalue because it is an enumerator constant.

Comment: Maybe you should quote when you reference from external source.

Comment: @texasbruce I believe this is from the C++11 ISO standard; I got it from cppreference.com.

Comment: I didn't pick this answer because i saw the macro on cppreference even before i post the question, and this answer does not really explain from a standard point of view but rather just interpret from the macro, which is not exactly true

Comment: @texasbruce The code posted above isn't a macro - it's actually taken from the C++ standard - but rather the formal definition of the range-based for loop. Specifically, the behavior of the range-based for loop should be exactly identical to the code shown above if it were to be expanded out and replaced. This doesn't mean it's a macro, though; the language is defined as "the statement `for (range_declaration : range_expression) loop_statement` is equivalent to the above code block." Does that make sense?

Comment: @Yakk rvalue references don't act as lvalue references. They act as lvalues (since they have a name).

Answer (score 6):

The range-based for-loop is not *macro expansion* but a true language feature. It does extend the lifetime of the temporary to the entire for body.

Answer (score 1):

The vector may be a prvalue, but the `int`s within are lvalues.

> the vector is prvalue, and cannot bind to int&

A vector can't bind to `int&`, regardless of its value category :) The `int`s within the vector are lvalues, though, and can bind to `int&`.

> Is it because for range loop is simply macro expansion...

Range for *is not* a macro expansion. It's a first class language construct.

Comment: I need to rephrase it but yes I mean the member of the vector is prvalue, but why you say they are lvalues?

Comment: Why do you say they are rvalues? They are lvalues because member functions of the vector that you use to access them return lvalue references.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, the vector is prvalue, and cannot bind to int&, but this one works correctly?

The error I believe you've made is that you're attributing value categories to objects rather than to expressions; You reason that because the vector object is a prvalue then so are its elements, and thus `int &v` can't be bound to those prvalues.

In fact value categories are an attribute of expressions rather than objects: As such it doesn't even make sense to reason about the elements of the range as having a value category and determining if the variable `int &v` is allowed to bind to those objects.

So while it's true that the expression that creates the vector is a prvalue, the created vector is just a regular object and its elements are just regular objects, all perfectly valid for referencing from a non-const lvalue reference typed variable.

Instead the intuitive explanation of the range-based for loop gives the correct answer: The variable gets initialized with each element of the range in turn and it just works.

---

Also, value categories are checked at compile time. If the code were actually illegal for the reason you give then you would get a compile error such as the following:

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'int'
   int &v = 10;
        ^   ~~
```

---

The undefined behavior you might expect to encounter at runtime has nothing to do with value categories: You might expect that the temporary vector's lifetime ends immediately after the range expression is evaluated, and thus the loop variable is a dangling reference into a vector that's been destroyed by the time the loop body first starts executing.

In fact the temporary vector has its lifetime extended for the entire duration of the loop, so there's no problem with dangling references on that account.